# includegraphics: option for downscaling only

Tags: conditionals, width, scaling, includegraphics

in the scripts for my students, I have a lot of screenshots which I include into the paper via e. g. `\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{"MyScreenshot"}` do scale them down which works fine.

But quite often, there are only screen snippets, which, by 0.7 would be zoomed to let's say 200 % or 300 %.

So I would like to define a macro like (pseudocode)

```
if actualwidth(#1) >= 0.7\linewidth then
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{#1}
else
   \includegraphics{#1}
endif
```

(Of course the 0.7 should be made an optional parameter as well, I know).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

LateComer
(LaTex Newbie age 55)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following defines the macro `\downgraphics` that has the same syntax as `\includegraphics`. It uses the options and puts the result in a box, additionally it includes the graphic in another box without using the options. Then the widths of those boxes are compared and the smaller one is used.

This assumes that you don't rotate or crop images with the options of `\includegraphics` but only use scaling options.

A status message is printed in the log and terminal that shows that the options were ignored for that graphic.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\newcommand\downgraphics[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \sbox0{\includegraphics{#2}}%
      \sbox2{\includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}}%
      \ifdim\wd2>\wd0
        \typeout
          {%
            Downgraphics:
            Width of original image is smaller than scaled one^^J
            \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
            (\the\wd0 \space< \the\wd2).^^J
            \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
            Using unscaled image #2.%
          }%
        \usebox0
      \else
        \usebox2
      \fi
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\downgraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\downgraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck-portrait}
\end{document}
```

This will print

```
Downgraphics: Width of original image is smaller than scaled one
              (53.15445pt < 172.5pt).
              Using unscaled image example-image-duck-portrait.
```

in the terminal.

Comment: Ist \sboxX somit eine Kurzversion \sbox{X} (zu letzterem habe ich mir gerade ein paar Posts durchgelesen) und \wdX bezieht sich immer auf die Breite der (vorher) definierten sbox X? Welche Werte darf da X annehmen (0..9 oder auch zweistellig/Buchstaben)?

Comment: @LateComer usually we write English here, but I'll answer your questions anyway: If you use `\sbox` with a one digit number (or a single macro) you don't need to use braces (but it doesn't hurt). `\sbox` only wants numbers for its first argument (or macros that ultimately expand to something TeX can consider a number), since `\sbox` accesses so called box registers. The first 10 of them (starting with 0) are by convention free for short term usage. Of those first 10 you should only use local assignments on the even ones and global assignments on the odd ones.

Comment: @LateComer `\wd<num>` is used to access the width of box register `<num>` (there is also `\ht` for height and `\dp` for depth). The values this `<num>` (for both `\wd` and `\sbox`) can be vary from engine to engine, in Knuthian TeX it used to be quite limited (up to 255), nowadays (thanks to eTeX) this number was considerably raised (to 32767 registers).

Comment: Sorry for the the German comment, no idea why fell back to my mother tongue in this comment. As your answers are in a way that people not speaking German can successfully guess what I was asking, I don't delete my comment.

Comment: @LateComer don't worry, German is my mother tongue as well and I can understand that sometimes one wants to switch back to it. I also think that you don't have to remove your comment. No harm done :)